# Fancy table: Multicol and multirow

Tags: tables, beamer, multirow, multicolumn, cell

Still dealing with fancy tables, now I am trying to get one with multicolumn and multirow cells.

I can get multicolumn cells right, but I am still struggling with multirow ones.

MWE in Beamer:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}

%%TABLE
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand*{\arraycolor}[1]{\protect\leavevmode\color{#1}}
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\columncolor{red!20}}c}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\columncolor{blue!20}}c}

\mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme[compress]{Singapore}
    \usecolortheme{orchid}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \sffamily
    \arrayrulecolor{white}
    \arrayrulewidth=1pt
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
    \rowcolors[\hline]{2}{.!50!White}{}
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{A|A|A|A|A|B|B|B|A}
            \rowcolor{.!50!Black}
            \multicolumn{5}{A|}{\arraycolor{White}\bfseries 14 subjects} &
            \multicolumn{3}{B|}{\arraycolor{White}\bfseries 10 subjects} &
            \multirow{2}{*}{\arraycolor{White}\bfseries Control}\\
            \rowcolor{.!50!Black}
            \multicolumn{3}{A|}{\arraycolor{White} Surface} &
            \multicolumn{2}{A|}{\arraycolor{White} Follicle} &
            \multicolumn{3}{B|}{\arraycolor{White} Surface} & \\
            No les & Non-inf & Inf & Non-inf & Inf & Cheek & Fh & Nose & Mock\\
        \end{tabular}
    }%
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

I need to make the "Control" cell span 2 rows properly, is it possible? Thanks!
[image: test]

**EDIT!**

I looked at the answers in the [possible duplicate question suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404872/are-beamer-hhline-and-tablexcolor-incompatible), but I still do not seem to get it right... I feel like it is almost there though.

Please check my updated MWE below:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}

%%TABLE
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\arraycolor{White}\bfseries}

\newcommand*{\arraycolor}[1]{\protect\leavevmode\color{#1}}
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\columncolor{red!20}}c}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\columncolor{blue!20}}c}

\mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme[compress]{Singapore}
    \usecolortheme{orchid}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \sffamily
    \arrayrulecolor{white}
    \arrayrulewidth=1pt
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
    \rowcolors[\hline]{2}{.!50!White}{}
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{A|A|A|A|A|B|B|B|A}
            \rowcolor{.!50!Black}
            \multicolumn{5}{A|}{\arraycolor{White}\bfseries 14 subjects} &
            \multicolumn{3}{B|}{\arraycolor{White}\bfseries 10 subjects} & \\
            \rowcolor{.!50!Black}
            \multicolumn{3}{A|}{\arraycolor{White} Surface} &
            \multicolumn{2}{A|}{\arraycolor{White} Follicle} &
            \multicolumn{3}{B|}{\arraycolor{White} Surface} &
            \multirow{-2}{*}{\thead{Control}}\\
            No les & Non-inf & Inf & Non-inf & Inf & Cheek & Fh & Nose & Mock\\
        \end{tabular}
    }%
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: test2]

Comment: As first step: Don't use `\multirow{2}...` in the first, but `\multirow{-2}...` in the second line. This way "Control" isn't covered by the effects of `\rowcolor`. The white line between the cells isn't covered this way.

Comment: Off-topic: There's definitely no need to load the `multicol` package.

Comment: What should those `>{\hsize=\hsize\tabcolsep\arrayrulewidth\relax}` instructions do? If I'm not mistaken, removing those doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @Skillmon you are right, those instructions don't do anything, I don't know where I took them from...

Comment: However, using `\multirow{-2}` in the second line, I still observe the line break, and "Control" isn't aligned vertically in the center of the double cell anymore...

Comment: It is as good vertically centred as it was before. Just with the deviation in the opposite direction that's because of the additional `\hline` rule width which isn't considered by `\multirow`. You could solve that with an additional `\raisebox{0.5\arrayrulewidth}{...}` inside the `\multirow`. I did say that this doesn't remove the white `\hline`. For this I don't have a solution. That's why I didn't post an answer.

Comment: unfortunately `beamer` heavely interfere with `hhline`, consequently the trick with use of  `hhline` instead of `\cline` used in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403365/hhline-not-working-with-multirow-and-cellcolor/403395#403395 doesn't work properly.

Comment: I had a look at the answers in the possible duplicate (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404872/are-beamer-hhline-and-tablexcolor-incompatible) but I still don't seem to get it right... I feel it's almost there though. Please check my edit. Thanks!

Comment: related bug report: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/434

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

[image]

the main problem is composing row colors and coloring of text. replacing them with more elementary approach and consider [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) answer on
[my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404872/are-beamer-hhline-and-tablexcolor-incompatible) the solution is:

```
 \documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}

%%TABLE
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\makeatletter
\let\zz\reset@color
\def\reset@color{\kern\z@\zz}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\arraycolor}[1]{\protect\leavevmode\color{#1}}
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\columncolor{red!20}}c}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\columncolor{blue!20}}c}

\mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme[compress]{Singapore}
    \usecolortheme{orchid}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \sffamily
    \arrayrulewidth=1pt
    \arrayrulecolor{white}
   \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{A|A|A|A|A|B|B|B|A}
            \rowcolor{.!50!Black}
            \multicolumn{5}{A|}{\color{White}\bfseries 14 subjects} &
            \multicolumn{3}{B|}{\color{White}\bfseries 10 subjects} & \\
            \hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{white}}--------%
                    >{\arrayrulecolor{red!20!black!60}}-}
            \rowcolor{.!50!Black}
            \arrayrulecolor{white}
            \multicolumn{3}{A|}{\color{White} Surface} &
            \multicolumn{2}{A|}{\color{White} Follicle} &
            \multicolumn{3}{B|}{\color{White} Surface} &
            \multirow{-2}{*}{\color{white}Control}\\
            \hline
            No les & Non-inf & Inf & Non-inf & Inf & Cheek & Fh & Nose & Mock\\
        \end{tabular}
    }%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
After almost four year I would for this table use a new package `tabularray` which better handle rows, columns and cells coloring:

[image]

Using it table code is shorter and more clear:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table}
    \centering
    \sffamily
    \small
\begin{tblr}{colspec={ c },
             colsep = 5pt,
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries, bg=black!80, fg=white},
             row{2} = {bg=black!80, fg=white},
             row{3} = {bg=red!30, fg=white},
             hlines={1pt, fg=white}, vlines={1pt, fg=white},
             }
\SetCell[c=5]{c} 14 subjects
    &   &   &   &   & \SetCell[c=3]{c} subjects
                        &   &   & \SetCell[r=2]{c} Control    \\
\SetCell[c=3]{c} Surface
    &   &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Follicle
                &   & \SetCell[c=3]{c} Surface
                        &   &   &         \\
No les 
    & Non-inf 
        & Inf 
            & Non-inf 
                & Inf 
                    & \SetCell{bg=blue7} Cheek 
                        & \SetCell{bg=blue7} Fh 
                            & \SetCell{bg=blue7} Nose 
                                &  Mock     \\
\end{tblr}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess the faint lines are a viewer problem. I can reproduce them with mac preview but with adobe reader everything looks fine.

Comment: For mac preview this seems to be an anti-aliasing problem. It goes away if "smooth text and line art" is not selected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. You won't have any faint line in the cell "control", whatever PDF viewer you use.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme[compress]{Singapore}
    \usecolortheme{orchid}
}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{A}{>{\columncolor{red!20}}c}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\columncolor{blue!20}}c}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\sffamily
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{NiceTabular}{AAAAABBBA}[rules={color=white,width=1pt},hvlines-except-borders,colortbl-like]
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{.!50!Black}{1,2}
\Body
  \RowStyle[nb-rows=2,color=white]{}
  \RowStyle[bold]{}
    \Block{1-5}{14 subjects} &&&&& \Block{1-3}{10 subjects} &&& \Block{2-1}{Control}\\ 
    \Block{1-3}{Surface} &&& \Block{1-2}{Follicle} && \Block{1-3}{Surface} \\ 
    No les & Non-inf & Inf & Non-inf & Inf & Cheek & Fh & Nose & Mock\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]