# Are beamer, hhline, and [table]{xcolor} incompatible?

Tags: tables, beamer, color, hhline

The following example works as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries\color{white}}
    \renewcommand{\theadgape}{}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
\centering
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}
    \arrayrulecolor{yellow}
    \def\clinecolor{\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{yellow}}--%
                            >{\arrayrulecolor{gray}}-}}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{ c | c | c }%
    \rowcolor{gray}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{AAA -- BBBB}}    &                                   \\
    \clinecolor
    \rowcolor{gray}
\color{white} AAA   &   \color{white} BBB   &   \multirow{-2}{*}{\thead{CCC}}   \\
    \hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{yellow}}-|-|-}
    \rowcolor{gray!25}
aaa                 &   bbb                 &   ccc                             \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!25}
ddd             &   eee                 &   fff
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But the following not:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries\color{white}}
    \renewcommand{\theadgape}{}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}
\centering
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}
    \arrayrulecolor{yellow}
    \def\clinecolor{\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{yellow}}--%
                            >{\arrayrulecolor{gray}}-}}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{ c | c | c }%
    \rowcolor{gray}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{AAA -- BBBB}}    &                                   \\
    \clinecolor
    \rowcolor{gray}
\color{white} AAA   &   \color{white} BBB   &   \multirow{-2}{*}{\thead{CCC}}   \\
    \hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{yellow}}-|-|-}
    \rowcolor{gray!25}
aaa                 &   bbb                 &   ccc                             \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!25}
ddd             &   eee                 &   fff                             \\
    \hhline{|-|-|-|}
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why are the in beamer rules so strangely misplaced? Is there some workaround?

Comment: maybe related: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=41452490#41452490 ???

Comment: @samcarter, yes, it seems that my question is related to the same problem. means, that i (we) should wait on fix in beamer. hopefully this will happen soon :-). btw, my question is based on one one similar question where i try to help, but i was surprised that solution done for `article` doesn't work in `beamer`.

Comment: related bug report: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/434

Comment: @samcarter, please see my answer on similar question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404661/fancy-table-multicol-and-multirow/405021#405021, in it i was faced with `\hhline` coloring problem (border of lines is still visible). so far i havent time to investigate, what is going on (is this only viewer artifact?). eventually i will ask new question about his.

Comment: I put a comment there - my guess would be viewer artefact.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

as samcarter commented

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries\color{white}}
    \renewcommand{\theadgape}{}
\usepackage{hhline}
\makeatletter
\let\zz\reset@color
\def\reset@color{\kern\z@\zz}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}
\centering
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}
    \arrayrulecolor{yellow}
    \def\clinecolor{\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{yellow}}--%
                            >{\arrayrulecolor{gray}}-}}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{ c | c | c }%
    \rowcolor{gray}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{AAA -- BBBB}}    &                                   \\
    \clinecolor
    \rowcolor{gray}
\color{white} AAA   &   \color{white} BBB   &   \multirow{-2}{*}{\thead{CCC}}   \\
    \hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{yellow}}-|-|-}
    \rowcolor{gray!25}
aaa                 &   bbb                 &   ccc                             \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!25}
ddd             &   eee                 &   fff                             \\
    \hhline{|-|-|-|}
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much! i'm curious, which package should have this patch? `beamer`? can we expect that it will be incorporate in it soon?

Comment: that isn't actually the right patch (but it's Ok and easiest to do in the document) beamer will probably change not to mess with `\reset@font` but also i'll probably change hhline and colortbl to protect themselves from the `\unskip` that beamer is adding.  but no promise on an update this side of christmas. @Zarko

Comment: thank you for explanation. it is not rush for this solution ... i only wondering, why use of rules from `booktabs` hasn't this problem (see Bernard answer).

Comment: @Zarko because they are rules (and rules don't get removed by \unskip) but colortbl and hhline make interesting (brilliantly ingenious:-) use of `\leaders` and leaders are removed by `\unskip`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As far as I can see, the problem still exists.  Am I right?  (I realize you didn't say which christmas :))

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I believe this problem still exists. If there is not an upcoming patch, it would perhaps be helpful to acknowledge this issue in the documentation to save people like me from struggling to figure out why it wasn't working for several hours... :-/

Comment: @MightyTyGuy I think the correct fix is should be in beamer over which I have no control but I could add a guard to colortbl's hhline I guess (but really hhline should have no reason to expect to need a guard there, I think)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. Has this issue already been reported to the maintainers of beamer?

Answer (score 4):

Use `booktabs` instead – more precisely  set `\above/belowrulesep` to `0pt` and use `\midrule`:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries\color{white}}
\renewcommand{\theadgape}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{test}
  \centering
  \setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
  \setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
  \setlength\lightrulewidth{2pt}
  \arrayrulecolor{yellow}
  \begin{tabular}{ c | c | c }%
    \rowcolor{gray}
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{AAA -- BBBB}} & \\
    \midrule
    \rowcolor{gray}
    \color{white} AAA & \color{white} BBB & \multirow{-2}{*}{\thead{CCC}} \\
    \midrule
    \rowcolor{gray!25}
    aaa & bbb & ccc \\
    \midrule
    \rowcolor{gray!25}
    ddd & eee & fff \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: good to know, that `booktabs` rule interact with `colortbl` (`[table]{xcolor}`) very diferently than standard `\hline` or `\hhline`.

Answer (score 3):

A variant with the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={ccc},
  row{1-2}={bg=gray,fg=white},
  row{1}={font=\bfseries},
  row{3-Z}={bg=lightgray},
  hline{2-Y}={yellow,wd=2pt},
  vline{2-Y}={yellow,wd=2pt},
}
\SetCell[c=2]{} AAA - BBBB & & \SetCell[r=2]{} CCC \\
AAA & BBB  & \\
aaa & bbb & ccc \\
ddd & eee & fff
\end{tblr}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have a key `hvlines-except-borders` to draw all the rules, excepted on the borders and in the blocks (created by `\Block`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\arrayrulecolor{yellow}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[hvlines-except-borders]
\RowStyle[nb-rows=2,color=white,rowcolor=gray]{}
\RowStyle[bold]{}
\Block{1-2}{AAA - BBBB} & & \Block{2-1}{CCC} \\
AAA & BBB \\
\RowStyle[nb-rows=2,rowcolor=gray!25]{}
aaa & bbb & ccc \\
ddd & eee & fff
\end{NiceTabular}

\arrayrulecolor{black}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the first code]

The result may seem disappointing. The vertical rules protrude below the array by a length equal to `\arrayrulewidth` by design... It's useful to have perfect joins with vertical rules in the most common situations...

However, with `nicematrix` (version ≥ 6.12), it's possible to draw a white rule at the end with `\Hline[color=white]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\arrayrulecolor{yellow}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[hvlines-except-borders]
\RowStyle[nb-rows=2,color=white,rowcolor=gray]{}
\RowStyle[bold]{}
\Block{1-2}{AAA - BBBB} & & \Block{2-1}{CCC} \\
AAA & BBB \\
\RowStyle[nb-rows=2,rowcolor=gray!25]{}
aaa & bbb & ccc \\
ddd & eee & fff
\Hline[color=white] 
\end{NiceTabular}

\arrayrulecolor{black}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

But there is another way. It's possible to define a new type of rule with its letter (`I`) and its command `\MyLine` and use it in the preamble and between the rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    custom-line = 
     {
       letter = I , 
       command = MyLine ,
       total-width = 2pt , 
       tikz = { line width = 2pt , yellow }
     }
  }


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cIcIc}[columns-width=15mm,cell-space-limits=3pt]
\RowStyle[nb-rows=2,color=white,rowcolor=gray]{}
\RowStyle[bold]{}
\Block{1-2}{AAA - BBBB} & & \Block{2-1}{CCC} \\
\MyLine
AAA & BBB \\
\MyLine
\RowStyle[nb-rows=2,rowcolor=gray!25]{}
aaa & bbb & ccc \\
\MyLine
ddd & eee & fff
\end{NiceTabular}

\arrayrulecolor{black}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Now, the vertical rules protrude below the array by a value of `\arrayrulewidth` but the value of `\arrayrulewidth` is zero. So, the output is perfect.