# Beamer: Multirow in fancy table

Tags: tables, beamer, multirow

Following up on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404661/fancy-table-multicol-and-multirow) I asked some time ago, I am facing a similar scenario, but for the life of me I do not seem to get it right with the solution provided in the question above, and I have no clue...

The following is a MWE, all I want to do is to merge rows vertically (multirow), so that "Preventative impacts of RA" and its corresponding "G5 vehicle UVB 40h" span 4 rows, and "Preventative impacts of RP" and its corresponding "G5 vehicle UVB 40h" span 3 rows.

How should I do it? Many thanks!!

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}

%%TABLE
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand*{\arraycolor}[1]{\protect\leavevmode\color{#1}}
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\columncolor{red!20}}c}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\columncolor{blue!20}}c}

\mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme[compress]{Singapore}
    \usecolortheme{orchid}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \sffamily
    \arrayrulecolor{white}
    \arrayrulewidth=1pt
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
    \rowcolors[\hline]{2}{.!50!White}{}
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{A|B|A}
            \rowcolor{.!50!Black}
            \arraycolor{White}\bfseries {\footnotesize Question} & \arraycolor{White}\bfseries {\footnotesize A} & \arraycolor{White}\bfseries {\footnotesize B}\\
            \bfseries {\scriptsize UVB impact on primary keratinocytes} & {\scriptsize G5 vehicle UVB 40h} & {\scriptsize G6 vehicle noUVB 40h}\\
            \bfseries {\scriptsize Preventative impact of RA} & {\scriptsize G1 RA\_1nM UVB 40h} & {\scriptsize G5 vehicle UVB 40h}\\
            & {\scriptsize G1 RA\_10nM UVB 40h} &\\
            & {\scriptsize G1 RA\_100nM UVB 40h} &\\
            & {\scriptsize G1 RA\_1$\mu$M UVB 40h} &\\
            \bfseries {\scriptsize Preventative impacts of RP} & {\scriptsize G2 RP\_0.1$\mu$M UVB 40h} & {\scriptsize G5 vehicle UVB 40h}\\
            & {\scriptsize G2 RP\_1$\mu$M UVB 40h} &\\
            & {\scriptsize G2 RP\_10$\mu$M 40h} &\\
        \end{tabular}
    }%
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image: test]

Comment: Please don't use `\resizebox` for elements that contain text, you will end up with a suboptimal font size, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text for further information

Comment: Which colour should the resulting cell have?

Comment: the multicol cells should have the color of the first single cell the text appears (here in all cases light pink)

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 6.1 of 2021-08-20).

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme[compress]{Singapore}
    \usecolortheme{orchid}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\sffamily
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\tiny
\begin{NiceTabular}
  [
    rules = {color=white,width=2pt} ,
    hvlines-except-borders ,
    cell-space-limits=3pt,
  ]
  {>{\bfseries}ccc}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolors{2}{red!20}{red!10}[cols={1,3},respect-blocks]
  \rowcolors{2}{blue!20}{blue!10}[cols=2]
  \cellcolor{red!50!black}{1-1,1-3}
  \cellcolor{blue!50!black}{1-2}
\Body
  \RowStyle[color=White]{\footnotesize}
  Question                                & \bfseries A           & \bfseries B \\
  UVB impact on primary keratinocytes     & G5 vehicle UVB 40h    & G6 vehicle noUVB 40h \\
  \Block{4-1}{Preventative impact of RA}  & G1 RA\_1nM UVB 40h    & \Block{4-1}{G5 vehicle UVB 40h} \\
                                          & G1 RA\_10nM UVB 40h   \\
                                          & G1 RA\_100nM UVB 40h  \\
                                          & G1 RA\_1$\mu$M UVB 40h  \\
  \Block{3-1}{Preventative impacts of RP} & G2 RP\_0.1$\mu$M UVB 40h & \Block{3-1}{G5 vehicle UVB 40h} \\
                                          & G2 RP\_1$\mu$M UVB 40h  \\
                                          & G2 RP\_10$\mu$M 40h     \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]